# Place an image centered between table cells

Tags: css

I have a table where first row only consist of small images. For each cell:
1. A small image, call it A, should be centered (of the cell).
2. A small image, call it B, should be centered around the middle between the cells, making half of the image "belong" to the left cell and half of it "belong" to the right cell.

A and B should be vertically aligned.
Making A centered in each cell is no problem of course. But I cannot make B placed between the cells. How do I do this?
Below is snippet (sorry, the images are missing).

If it helps, image A will be used (if clicked) for the user to remove the column and B will be used (if clicked) to insert a column between two existing columns.

```html
<html>

<style>
.table_layout_1 {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table.table_layout_1 td, table.table_layout_1 th {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 2px;
}

table.table_layout_1 tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2;}

table.table_layout_1 tr:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

table.table_layout_1 th {
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}

table.table_layout_1 input {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 4px 4px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid red
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

img.table_layout_1_remove_col {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
}

img.table_layout_1_add_col {
    float: right;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
}
</style>

<body>
<form action="" method="post" name="form_name">
<table id="table_id_1" class="table_layout_1">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img class="table_layout_1_remove_col" src="minus_sign_red_circle.svg" alt="Remove column">
      <img class="table_layout_1_add_col" src="plus_sign_green_circle.svg" alt="Add column">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img class="table_layout_1_remove_col" src="minus_sign_red_circle.svg" alt="Remove column">
      <img class="table_layout_1_add_col" src="plus_sign_green_circle.svg" alt="Add column">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Value</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="cell_0_0" value="Row 1"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="cell_0_1" value="1000"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="cell_1_0" value="Row 2"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="cell_1_1" value="2000"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="cell_2_0" value="Row 3"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="cell_2_1" value="3000"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="cell_3_0" value="Row 4"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="cell_3_1" value="4000"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give `position: relative` to the `<td>` tag and `position: absolute` to the `<img>` which you want to center. Along with that, you need to give top and right css properties. This way, the image will always be fixed to the position you need irrespective of the width of the td.

Have updated the code snippet below:
Observer that I have added new class `td_1` to `<td>` tag for some css.

```html
<html>

<style>
.table_layout_1 {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table.table_layout_1 td, table.table_layout_1 th {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 2px;
}

table.table_layout_1 tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2;}

table.table_layout_1 tr:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

table.table_layout_1 th {
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}

table.table_layout_1 input {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 4px 4px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid red
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

img.table_layout_1_remove_col {
    display: block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
}
.td_1 { /*New class for position relative*/
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
img.table_layout_1_add_col {
    position: absolute; /*Give position absolute*/
    top: calc(50% - 16px); /*top = 50% - 16px for vertically aligning to middle. 16px is used because image's height is 32px.*/
    right: -16px; /*right = -16px so that, image is only half inside current <td> and rest half goes to nest <td>*/
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
}
</style>

<body>
<form action="" method="post" name="form_name">
<table id="table_id_1" class="table_layout_1">
  <tr>
    <td class="td_1">
      <img class="table_layout_1_remove_col" src="minus_sign_red_circle.svg" alt="Remove column">
      <img class="table_layout_1_add_col" src="plus_sign_green_circle.svg" alt="Add column">
    </td>
    <td class="td_1">
      <img class="table_layout_1_remove_col" src="minus_sign_red_circle.svg" alt="Remove column">
      <img class="table_layout_1_add_col" src="plus_sign_green_circle.svg" alt="Add column">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Value</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="cell_0_0" value="Row 1"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="cell_0_1" value="1000"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="cell_1_0" value="Row 2"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="cell_1_1" value="2000"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="cell_2_0" value="Row 3"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="cell_2_1" value="3000"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="cell_3_0" value="Row 4"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="cell_3_1" value="4000"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that position relative on the parent td is needed for the position absolute on the img having it absolute relative the td area? Reading the css docs for position absolute: "The element is positioned relative to its first positioned (not static) ancestor element".

Comment: Just to be clear, this proposal works well and according to my needs. Thanks Sunil!

Comment: I would also suggest you to read this: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of your case but you could use `relative` positioning for the image.

Modify the `left` and `top` values of the `img` according to your needs.

```css
.table_layout_1 {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table.table_layout_1 td, table.table_layout_1 th {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 2px;
}

table.table_layout_1 tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2;}

table.table_layout_1 tr:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

table.table_layout_1 th {
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}

table.table_layout_1 input {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 4px 4px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid red
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

img.table_layout_1_remove_col {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
}

img.table_layout_1_add_col {
    position:relative;
  left:150px;
  top:-15px;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="post" name="form_name">
<table id="table_id_1" class="table_layout_1">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img class="table_layout_1_remove_col" src="minus_sign_red_circle.svg" alt="Remove column">
      <img class="table_layout_1_add_col" src="plus_sign_green_circle.svg" alt="Add column">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img class="table_layout_1_remove_col" src="minus_sign_red_circle.svg" alt="Remove column">
      <img class="table_layout_1_add_col" src="plus_sign_green_circle.svg" alt="Add column">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Value</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="cell_0_0" value="Row 1"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="cell_0_1" value="1000"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="cell_1_0" value="Row 2"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="cell_1_1" value="2000"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="cell_2_0" value="Row 3"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="cell_2_1" value="3000"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="cell_3_0" value="Row 4"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="cell_3_1" value="4000"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the proposal, but the vertical alignment doesn't become correct here. Probably can be fixed, but I prefer Sunil's answer since it works irrespective of the td width.

Comment: Happy that you found a solution :)